# Help understanding notation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, notation

I'm working on a problem in a QM course, and I need some help decoding the notation used. The problem reads:

"Show that while the orbital angular momentum $\mathbf L_p$ of the p-th electron in an atom does not commute with $2/\mathbf{r_{pq}}$ (i.e. with $H_{ee}$), $\mathbf L=\sum \mathbf {L_i}$ does. i.e. $[\mathbf L, \mathbf H_{ee}]=0$."

I've written it exactly as given, including all bold-typed symbols. There is no extra context.

I'm wondering what the symbols used here represent, e.g. $\mathbf{r_{pq}}$ and $H_{ee}$ or $\mathbf{H}_{ee}$. Is this some type of standard Hamiltonians that I should be familiar with? Is $\mathbf{r_{pq}}=\mathbf{r_q} - \mathbf{r_p}$?

Comment: Which textbook/reference?

Comment: @Qmechanic, it's not from a textbook (that I know of anyhow). It's from an assignment given in a master level QM course.

Comment: Bold letters usually denote vectors, which does not make much sense for $2/\mathbf{r_{pq}}$.

Comment: I think you have to ask the instructor.

Comment: I realise this isn't a question easily answered  by anyone but the instructor. I'll ask him as well. I just hoped for a "you missed this standard definition" type answer while it's still the weekend. Anyhow, thanks for the input!

Answer (score 1):

The subscript in $H_{ee}$ could denote interacting electrons, (see, for example, [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1009.6051)). And, yes, the most straightforward interpretation of $\mathbf{r}_{pq}$ is then their relative position.